# Angular $rootScope and $window.location

Tags: angularjs

The code below stores a login object in $rootScope, however when I retrieve it is undefined. There's a $window.location change afterwards, could that be the reason?

```
    var promise = ... $http request
    promise.then(
        function(response) {
            $rootScope.login = response.login;
            $window.location.href = 'main.html#/mngips';
        },
        function() { 
        }
```

Comment: Of course this is the reason, you reload the app.

Comment: So how can I store the login object? I redirect to the main page of the application after the user logs in

Comment: Try using the $location service to change paths instead. $location.path('mngips').

Comment: I have a login page and a main application page. The user logs in, in the response the app receives the login object and stores it for later use. Afterwards, the user needs to see the main page. If not use $window.location that reloads the app, what's the alternative?

Comment: @ScottVickers thanks, but doesn't work, the login url is `web/login.html` and I need to redirect to `web/main.html#/mngips`, I tried `$location.path('main.html#/mngips');` but doesn't work either

Comment: If you have to keep this architecture, you will have to use some kind of persistent layer, like sessionStorage or localStorage

Comment: @BorisCharpentier I don't have to keep this architecture, what's the best practice to navigate from login page to main page in an application?

Comment: Use only one html file, use $location and $route to navigate

Comment: how can I use one html file if the page layout between the login page and the app main page is completely different?